# Where should I get my letters of recommendation, coming from outside academia?

Tags: application, recommendation-letter, industry, psychology

I'm considering applying for grad school (psychology). However, I've been in industry for two years. Also, I never connected with my professors... Here are some of my options for letters of recommendation/reference, none of them are very good, but please help me pick the two best (or think of other possibilities). In case it's important, I studied computer science, minored in philosophy, graduated 2 years ago, and now I work as a software engineer.

1. Manager. Only worked with him 6 months. He doesn't have a lot of visibility into the work I've done.
2. Coworker. Only worked with him 6 months. He has quite a bit of visibility into the work I've done.
3. Former Teaching Assistant from Philosophy class. Talked with him quite a bit and he marked all my essays across three different classes, so he should remember me.
4. Former Philosophy Professor. Just one semester, but I went to a handful of his office hours, and his was one of the last classes I took, so he might remember me.
5. Former Psychology Professor. I don't remember this course, and she wouldn't remember me (never went to office hours)

Comment: Reach out to 3. & 4. You could try to combine 1. & 2. i.e. 2. can help 1. write a meaningful LoR.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Erik Westlund's answer to that question looks general enough to be useful here, but I'm not sure that question is a full duplicate. If someone works in technical field X, and wants to do a PhD in that field, it's straightforward enough to recommend getting a letter from a manager, mentor, or coworker. Now, if someone works in a technical field Y, and wants to do a PhD in a social science Z - well, it seems to me that the considerations might be rather different.